# Font awesome Icons disappearing when ? is in "href"

Tags: html

I am trying to use some font awesome icons to allow reposts of some blogs, but every time I make the "href=" more complicated the icons disappear.

Could anyone tell me why this would work:

```
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet">Tweet <i class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-2x"></i></a>
```

But this won't:

```
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<a class="btn-cta-freequote" href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=Hello%20world">Tweet <i class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-2x"></i></a>
```

The difference being: "?text=Hello%20world"

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pEwgyg

[image]

Only one 'Tweet' is appearing and there should be two.

Thanks

Comment: Humor me. See if ``target="_blank"``, to open twitter in a new tab solves the issue...

Comment: Both work for me http://www.bootply.com/VtcxT8BVvS

Comment: Both worked for me as well. Are you able to provide a fiddle or Stack Snippet that illustrates the problem?

Comment: I added code pen sample: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pEwgyg

Comment: In  your own example they work fine for me

Comment: Alex: I have target set to `"_blank"`, but no luck.

Comment: Can you get a screenshot of what you see?

Comment: do you have an adblocker turned on? I could reproduce your testcase using ublock.

Comment: Screenshot added.

Comment: Thats it. Definitely the ad blocker. Thank You all for you help.

Comment: Weird. I checked in all of my browsers and your codepen is showing both. I'm thinking @imjared might be on to something. Some 3rd party script.

Answer (score 3):

Ublock origin will block lots of Twitter/FB/social links. Turn your adblock off and *presto*.